# GetCompletionValue with IIFE trigger errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jint

I get a exception if I try to use `GetCompletionValue` with `Invoker`.
How can i execute the `run` function with IIFE lexical scope?

Javascript:

```cs
(function(){
  function run() {
    logger('teste logger');

    var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter('log.txt');
        file.WriteLine('Write file test');
        file.Dispose();
  }

  return {
    'run': run
  }
})();
```

My Invoker:

```cs
public void Execute(string code, string functionName)
{
  _engine.Execute(code).GetCompletionValue();
  _engine.Invoke(functionName); // -- run function
}
```

Error:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.ArgumentException
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Jint.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Can only invoke functions'
   at Jint.Engine.Invoke(JsValue value, Object thisObj, Object[] arguments)
   at Jint.Engine.Invoke(String propertyName, Object thisObj, Object[] arguments)
   at Jint.Engine.Invoke(String propertyName, Object[] arguments)
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can i execute the run function with IIFE lexical scope?

The reason why causes 'System.ArgumentException' is the codes in `Javascript`. Function codes of format are invalid. Change it like codes below:

```
          function run() {
            logger('teste logger');

            var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter('log.txt');
                file.WriteLine('Write file test');
                file.Dispose();
          }
```

As for lexical scope, you could also try these codes below:

```
        String code = @"

          function go(){
                function run() {
                logger('teste logger');

                var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter('log.txt');
                    file.WriteLine('Write file test');
                    file.Dispose();
                }

                return run();
            }

        ";
        Execute(code, "go");
```

> ConsoleApplication Examples of using Jint in .NET Core 3.1

```
class Program
{

    public static Engine _engine = new Engine(cfg => cfg.AllowClr());


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _engine.SetValue("logger", new Action<object>(Console.WriteLine));

        String code = @"

          function run() {
            logger('teste logger');

            var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter('log.txt');
                file.WriteLine('Write file test');
                file.Dispose();
          }

        ";
        Execute(code, "run");
    }

    public static void Execute(string code, string functionName)
    {
        _engine.Execute(code).GetCompletionValue();
        _engine.Invoke(functionName); // -- run function
    }
}
```

> Test

It works as `run` function expected.

[image]